# What is the best way to cluster huge amounts (250 million) of high dimensional vectors?

Tags: clustering

There are a lot of clustering algorithms in machine learning. Most of them work well on reasonable small data. For huge data sets in the hundreds of millions most of them are unusable due to memory consumption or processing time.

I am using clustering to find matching pairs of vectors. The problem is that there are either too many vectors in the buckets which makes further processing too expensive or the bucket sizes are fine but the matches are too often in different buckets.

I already tried hierarchical k-means and lsh but both did not meet my goals. I also tried the [annoy](https://github.com/spotify/annoy) repository which works fine on smaller sets but due to memory consumption I cannot use it. Most of the clustering algorithms work fine for data up to 10 million vectors but are too expensive for larger data.

My goal is to cluster the data in buckets that should not contain more than 1000 vectors. Matches should be in same bucket almost certainly.

I also thought about preprocessing/transforming the vector data to make clustering easier but did not find anything useful.

Are there any alternatives I am missing?

Comment: What about k-means and hierarchical clustering did not meet your goals? What are your goals? How are we to compare alternative clustering algorithms when making an answer?

Comment: Take a sample of your huge data set. Run `kmeans()` with a suitable `k`. An elbow analysis is handy to determine a reasonable `k`. Use `predict()` to determine the cluster of each out-of-sample vector. Consider reducing the dimensionality of your data before you do all of this.

Comment: I don't know which LSH methods you tried, but there's a lot of different varieties available, with different approaches and assumptions baked into them. I point this out here just in case you tried *one* LSH, found that it wasn't what you wanted and moved on. There could be some adjustments or alternative LSH strategies which might be valuable. The way that you've revised the question makes it sound what you need is *some kind* of LSH, and more specifically an LSH that has certain properties.

Answer (score 0):

> I am using clustering to find matching pairs of vectors.

This is just a shot in the dark really since I'm not sure exactly what your are trying to do. Based on the sentence above, there are tools in bioinformatics to align DNA or protein sequences against each other on a large scale (e.g. [minimap2](https://github.com/lh3/minimap2), [BLAST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/BLAST_(biotechnology)), [VSEARCH](https://github.com/torognes/vsearch)). If you can formulate your problem in terms of sequence alignment, then maybe you can leverage on those open-source tools